# Unable to change the file-format of New Text Document

Tags: windows-xp, notepad

I'm trying to change the **file-format** of **New Text Document** to html.But the file-extension was changed and still it open as a .txt file.

Comment: How are you trying to open the file? Have you got the "hide known extensions" option checked?

Comment: just i click the context-menu and created the new text doc and tried to rename and change the file-format to .html

Comment: @ChrisF, What does it hide known extensions?

Comment: I'm not on XP so I can't remember exactly where the option is, but if you hide extensions when you try to rename you might end up with `file.html.txt` which will still be a text file not a html file

Comment: @ChrisF,exactly the same problem!!!!

Comment: @ChrisF, Chris,i couldn't get the initial 100 rep in my superuser a/c eventhough i've got more than 700+ in other SE sites..The reason i mentioned here is i'm not able to ask a qn in meta.superuser, because it req 5+ rep..Help me out!!1

Comment: This association issue is [known about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep) and should be fixed very soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your comments you appear to have "Hide extensions of known file types" set.

This means that when you create a new text file you see:

> NewFileName

rather than:

> NewFileName.txt

This also means that when you rename the file all you are changing is the **filename** part, but not the **extension**. This means that Windows still treats the file as a text file rather than html file. What you have is a file called:

> NewFileName.html.txt

Turn off this option. Full details can be found [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-Hidden-File-Extensions-in-Windows-XP) but you need to go to Folder Options and select the View tab. Then find the "Hide extensions for known file types" option and clear it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do : `right click` on the file and choose `open with` and select `internet explorer`

Comment: it was opened with .txt extension in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if using notepad or some similar editor to edit the file, make sure that you are saving as type "All Files (*.*)", with the extension ".html", and save as "filename.html".

Answer (score 0):

When using "save as" in the text editor, change the codification to UTF-16 either LE or BE and also save the file name as .html.

Here is an example:

```
     File name: Test.html 
     Type:  can be *.txt or all files
     Codification: UTF-16 LE
```